# How to center the title in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am learning to use `Rmarkdown` to prepare my technical document. One thing I am trying to figure out is how to center the headers? Do you guys have any ideas??

Answer (score 59):

You can mix html with markdown. For example

```
<center> <h1>heading 1</h1> </center>
```

There may be ways to center actual markdown instead of centering html, but that's easy enough.

Answer (score 3):

In knitted html file title is in `<h1></h1>` and author's name is in `<h4></h4>`. So you can easily use css to modify their appearances.

Use this code chunk anywhere in your rmd file and knit -

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
h1, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```
````

If you want to bold the text or change color then simply use css. For example:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
h1, h4 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

At a point where you are referencing the heading, you can do:

```
[Heading](#heading)

and then 
### <h3 align="center" id="heading">Heading</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to adjust the alignment of headings.

For example, you may center section headings of level 1, 2, and 3 with the CSS code below:

```
h1, h2, h3 {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Extracted from: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/center-heading.html